# Auto-update on shutdown

Tags: bash, shutdown

In my system I have come up with the following bash alias:

alias updt='apt update -y && apt upgrade -y && apt autoremove -y'

I run this almost every time I use the system. My question is:

***Is it possible to make the system run this command whenever I shutdown the computer?***

*As a bonus: Could I do so just like we have on Windows to make the system auto-update when I use the shutdown option directly from the upper right corner of the desktop environment?*

Comment: See http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/systemd-halt.service.8.html for the mechanism to run an executable at shutdown, power off, restart, et al. As to running your executable when you use the icon at upper right? No idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yes. It's a setting.**

Apt *already* does background apt updates and apt upgrades...

```
/lib/systemd/system/apt-daily.timer           // update
/lib/systemd/system/apt-daily-upgrade.timer   // upgrade
```

...all you really need to do is stay out of it's way, and to tweak the settings as shown below.

---

Edit the config file `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades`:

Example command: `$ sudo nano /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades`

**Step 1: Edit your sources**. The default settings include only the -security repo. You can update this to include all your sources. Best practice is to add stable, reliable sources like -updates and -security (those two should be the great majority of your upgrades!) This is NOT recommended for -proposed or other testing/unstable sources.

```
// Automatically upgrade packages from these (origin:archive) pairs
//
// Note that in Ubuntu security updates may pull in new dependencies
// from non-security sources (e.g. chromium). By allowing the release
// pocket these get automatically pulled in.
Unattended-Upgrade::Allowed-Origins {
        "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}";
        "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}-security";
        // Extended Security Maintenance; does not necessarily exist for
        // every release and this system may not have it installed, but if
        // available, the policy for updates is such that unattended-upgrades
        // should also install from here by default.
        "${distro_id}ESM:${distro_codename}";
        "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}-updates";
//      "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}-proposed";
//      "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}-backports";
};
```

**Step 2: Enable Autoremove**. Simply uncomment the final line:

```
// Do automatic removal of unused packages after the upgrade
// (equivalent to apt-get autoremove)
//Unattended-Upgrade::Remove-Unused-Dependencies "true";
```

**Step 3: Do upgrades at shutdown** instead of in the background. Simply uncomment the final line:

```
// Install all unattended-upgrades when the machine is shutting down
// instead of doing it in the background while the machine is running
// This will (obviously) make shutdown slower
//Unattended-Upgrade::InstallOnShutdown "true";
```